# Positioning arrow in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Hello I wanted to draw a curved line from "Bit" to "12" but the arrow goes to the middle of the box. How can I get it to the front line of this box? Or a little bit above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Aktiviert EC-Schriftarten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Dateikodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         % Deutsche Einstellung
\usepackage{lmodern}                % Latin Modern
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (15) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm] {$15$};
        \node (14) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 15] {$14$};
        \node (13) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 14] {$13$};
        \node (12) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 13] {$12$};
        \node (11) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 12] {$11$};
        \node (10) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 11] {$10$};
        \node (9) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 10] {$9$};
        \node (8) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 9] {$8$};
        \node (7) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 8] {$7$};
        \node (6) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 7] {$6$};
        \node (5) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 6] {$5$};
        \node (4) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 5] {$4$};
        \node (3) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 4] {$3$};
        \node (2) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 3] {$2$};
        \node (1) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 2] {$1$};
        \node (0) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 1] {$0$};
        \coordinate[below left=0mm of 15] (RWLeft);
        \coordinate[below right=0mm of 0] (RWRight);
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=15pt}, minimum height=6mm]
        (RWRight) -- (RWLeft)
        node[anchor=north,midway,below=15pt] {Word};
        \coordinate[above left=0mm of 7] (AddrLeftRes);
        \coordinate[above right=0mm of 0] (AddrRightRes);
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=15pt}, minimum height=6mm]
        (AddrLeftRes) -- (AddrRightRes)
        node[anchor=south,midway,above=15pt] {Byte};
        
        \node [inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] (O) at (12) {};
        \node [align=center] (origin) at ([xshift=-1.8cm,yshift=1.3cm]O) {Bit};
        \draw [shorten <=.1cm,stealth-] (O) to [out=0,in=-90] (origin.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the `(O)` node? This eems enough `\node [align=center] (origin) at ([xshift=-1.8cm,yshift=1.3cm]12) {Bit};` places `Bit` in relation to node 12 and ` \draw [shorten <=.1cm,stealth-] (12.north west) to [out=90,in=-90] (origin.west);` draws a line.

Comment: @nico.wagner  something like the answer below -- do note that u are working in the reverse direction with the arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Aktiviert EC-Schriftarten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Dateikodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         % Deutsche Einstellung
\usepackage{lmodern}                % Latin Modern
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (15) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm] {$15$};
        \node (14) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 15] {$14$};
        \node (13) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 14] {$13$};
        \node (12) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 13] {$12$};
        \node (11) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 12] {$11$};
        \node (10) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 11] {$10$};
        \node (9) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 10] {$9$};
        \node (8) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 9] {$8$};
        \node (7) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 8] {$7$};
        \node (6) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 7] {$6$};
        \node (5) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 6] {$5$};
        \node (4) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 5] {$4$};
        \node (3) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 4] {$3$};
        \node (2) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 3] {$2$};
        \node (1) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 2] {$1$};
        \node (0) [draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, right=0cm of 1] {$0$};
        \coordinate[below left=0mm of 15] (RWLeft);
        \coordinate[below right=0mm of 0] (RWRight);
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=15pt}, minimum height=6mm]
        (RWRight) -- (RWLeft)
        node[anchor=north,midway,below=15pt] {Word};
        \coordinate[above left=0mm of 7] (AddrLeftRes);
        \coordinate[above right=0mm of 0] (AddrRightRes);
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=15pt}, minimum height=6mm]
        (AddrLeftRes) -- (AddrRightRes)
        node[anchor=south,midway,above=15pt] {Byte};
        
%       \node [inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] (O) at (12) {};
        \node [align=center] (Bit) at ([xshift=-1.8cm,yshift=1.3cm]12) {Bit};
        \draw [stealth-] (12) to [out=90,in=0] (Bit);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may liked (at least code is significantly shorter):

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=3.5cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Aktiviert EC-Schriftarten
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         % Deutsche Einstellung
\usepackage{lmodern}                % Latin Modern
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, 
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                positioning,
                babel% added for compatibility with babel ...            
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 0mm,
  start chain = A going right,
     B/.style = {decorate,
                decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4mm,
                raise=1mm},
                very thick, pen colour=black},
    N/.style = {draw, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=8mm, outer sep=0pt,
               on chain}  
                        ]
\foreach \i in {15,14,...,0}  
    \node[N] {$\i$};   % node names names are from A-1 to A-16
%
\node (aux) [above=5mm of A-2] {Bit};
\draw [-stealth] (aux) to [bend left] (A-4.north);
% braces
\draw[B]    (A-7.north west)  -- node[above=5mm] {Byte}  (A-16.north east);
\draw[B]    (A-16.south east) -- node[below=5mm] {Word}  (A-1.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```